# python-select specific excel files from folder to merge

Tags: xlsx

new python writer here just wanting to see if i can get help with this code that i am working with. i have a folder where i just want specific files for example:

- report1-AM.xlsx
- report1-PM.xlsx
- report1-all day.xlsx
- report2-AM.xlsx
- report2-PM.xlsx
- report2-all.xlsx day and so on about 45 reports

i am wanting to see if i can just get all reports under report(#)-all day.

this is what i am working with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame() 
    for file in files:
   if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
    df = df.append(pd.read_excel(file), ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: i think you need something like `if file.endswith('.xlsx') and 'all day' in file:`

Comment: if not, you need to use regex pattern matching .